# How to add children and descendants to a tree in react?

Tags: reactjs

As far as I've read parents should store childrens data which would solve my problem simply because I could iterate through the tree, but I'm not able to come up with a solution that manages to do that in react.

[image: Descendant layout]

To clarify:
My goal is to convert my JSX-Layout to a JSON-Object so that I can send it to my backend for further processing.
Currently each of the nodes handle the adding of a new child in themself. All nodes only know their immediate children.
The problem now is that I don't know how I could read the entire tree data structure.

For example: In Java I could simply add a child to a node by just accessing the node's reference and adding the new node to the list of childrens. Since I use functional components in React I'm not able to do that and probably need to pass down a event from the parent nodes to register new nodes from children but I simply cant wrap my head around it. I don't see how that is possible with React, but I'm certain that it's just me misunderstanding something or trying for too long.

Any help is appreciated!

**TL;DR:**
How do I manage state in trees so that I can access the whole tree and add/remove children to/from children and their descendants?

I tried to pass down an event from the parent through the whole hierarchy where every child would add its children but I'm not sure if that is correct since it seems really unclean.

Comment: Here's a hint, don't treat your data-set as components, instead, treat it as an array, or object, then loop over this array or object to produce JSX elements that you can draw in the view. I've got no time to answer, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a way to traverse your tree. There are various ways to traverse a tree to generate a full depiction of its elements (to make a JSON object, for example), but I think you probably want to use in-order traversal. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) is a link with more details about some different tree traversal strategies.

If you're looking for a way to access a React component's children, you can read this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/08/react-children-iteration-methods/) for inspiration.